# Error installing ESP-IDF extension on VSCode during the 'Installing Python virtual environment' step

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, espressif-idf

I used the extension normally, but then I tried to do something with the Arduino library, and something went wrong.
So I tried to reinstall it, I used a specific version that the company uses in the products, so the ESP-frameworks (IDF, MDF, and components) are saved in the repository. The installer used is version 2.16, but it's never gives an error.
So I followed the step-by-step process, installing the ESP-tools. It creates the Espressif file, I added the paths for MDF and components in the user's paths. In Visual Studio Code, I reinstalled the extension, and then in the initial setup, I used the customized one and the files from the versions I created (I have already done this procedure 3 other times, and it worked fine). However, in the Python Environment, an error related to "virtualenv" keeps appearing. So I tried to install it manually, but it continues to give an error. I tried to install it using the Python terminal of ESP-IDF, and also in the Python terminal itself. I have no clue what is happening. I'm attaching the log here:

```
idf-python-3.11.2-embed-win64.zip progress: 99.91% (13763.88 / 13775.83) KB
idf-python-3.11.2-embed-win64.zip progress: 100.00% (13775.83 / 13775.83) KB
Extracted c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2 ...
Looking in links: c:\Users\GUSTAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppmw4rjpd

Processing c:\users\gustavohp\appdata\local\temp\tmppmw4rjpd\setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl

Processing c:\users\gustavohp\appdata\local\temp\tmppmw4rjpd\pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl

Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip

  WARNING: The scripts pip3.11.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Successfully installed pip-22.3.1 setuptools-65.5.0


Downloading Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32) based on GCC
Found xtensa-esp32-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32-S2) based on GCC
Found xtensa-esp32s2-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32-S3) based on GCC
Found xtensa-esp32s3-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Toolchain for 32-bit RISC-V based on GCC
Found riscv32-esp-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Toolchain for ESP32 ULP coprocessor
Found esp32ulp-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Toolchain for ESP32-S2 ULP coprocessor
Found esp32s2ulp-elf in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading CMake build system
Found cmake in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading OpenOCD for ESP32
Found openocd-esp32 in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Ninja build system
Found ninja in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading IDF wrapper tool for Windows
Found idf-exe in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading Ccache (compiler cache)
Found ccache in c:\Espressif\dist
Downloading dfu-util (Device Firmware Upgrade Utilities)
Found dfu-util in c:\Espressif\dist

Using existing Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32) based on GCC in c:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0
Using existing Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32-S2) based on GCC in c:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32s2-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0
Using existing Toolchain for Xtensa (ESP32-S3) based on GCC in c:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32s3-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0
Using existing Toolchain for 32-bit RISC-V based on GCC in c:\Espressif\tools\riscv32-esp-elf\esp-2021r1-8.4.0
Using existing Toolchain for ESP32 ULP coprocessor in c:\Espressif\tools\esp32ulp-elf\2.28.51-esp-20191205
Using existing Toolchain for ESP32-S2 ULP coprocessor in c:\Espressif\tools\esp32s2ulp-elf\2.28.51-esp-20191205
Using existing CMake build system in c:\Espressif\tools\cmake\3.16.4
Using existing OpenOCD for ESP32 in c:\Espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.10.0-esp32-20210401
Using existing Ninja build system in c:\Espressif\tools\ninja\1.10.2
Using existing IDF wrapper tool for Windows in c:\Espressif\tools\idf-exe\1.0.1
Using existing Ccache (compiler cache) in c:\Espressif\tools\ccache\3.7
Using existing dfu-util (Device Firmware Upgrade Utilities) in c:\Espressif\tools\dfu-util\0.9

Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-20.24.5-py3-none-any.whl (3.7 MB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.7
  Using cached distlib-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.12.2
  Using cached filelock-3.12.4-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting platformdirs<4,>=3.9.1
  Using cached platformdirs-3.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Installing collected packages: distlib, platformdirs, filelock, virtualenv
Successfully installed distlib-0.3.7 filelock-3.12.4 platformdirs-3.10.0 virtualenv-20.24.5
Creating a new Python environment in c:\Espressif\python_env\idf4.3_py3.11_env
Installing virtualenv
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
WARNING: Git describe was unsuccessul: b''
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\gustavohp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe: No module named virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1675, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1671, in main
    action_func(args)
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1379, in action_install_python_env
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'virtualenv', idf_python_env_path],
  File "subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\Espressif\\tools\\idf-python\\3.11.2\\python.exe', '-m', 'virtualenv', 'c:\\Espressif\\python_env\\idf4.3_py3.11_env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Command failed: "c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe" "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py" install-python-env
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
WARNING: Git describe was unsuccessul: b''
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\gustavohp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe: No module named virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1675, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1671, in main
    action_func(args)
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1379, in action_install_python_env
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'virtualenv', idf_python_env_path],
  File "subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\Espressif\\tools\\idf-python\\3.11.2\\python.exe', '-m', 'virtualenv', 'c:\\Espressif\\python_env\\idf4.3_py3.11_env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Command failed: "c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe" "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py" install-python-env
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
WARNING: Git describe was unsuccessul: b''
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\gustavohp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
c:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe: No module named virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1675, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1671, in main
    action_func(args)
  File "c:\Users\gustavohp\Documents\esp-frameworks\esp-idf\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1379, in action_install_python_env
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'virtualenv', idf_python_env_path],
  File "subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\Espressif\\tools\\idf-python\\3.11.2\\python.exe', '-m', 'virtualenv', 'c:\\Espressif\\python_env\\idf4.3_py3.11_env']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

If anyone has any clues, I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the Esressif-IDE (Eclipse-based one), don't use the existing version when configuring the plugin in VS Code.

Also, when it's asking for the path for the Espressif folder, don't use the "X:/Espressif" (where X is the drive you previously installed the tools). I used the folder under "path_to_user_folder/user/esp" and "path_to_user_folder/user/esp/tools" for the paths, and it finally configured the plugin.